# How to fix Windows dual boot with Manjaro?

Tags: windows, dual-boot, manjaro

I've done a full system update of Manjaro Linux, but the laptop has shutted down due to low battery. After turning it on again, everything was working well, so I restarted the update and this time has been completed. Next, I restarted laptop to use Windows and it wasn't on boot menu anymore. 
I can read all Windows's partition from Linux (can even use them), but I can't boot it. 
The BIOS is UEFI with secure boot off

P.S.: Linux and Windows were in dual boot

Comment: Possibly related: [After installing Manjaro, windows is not showing in boot menu](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/296574)

Comment: Well, this was the solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. [Fix Windows' bootloader](https://superuser.com/questions/388760/fix-broken-windows-7-boot-loader)
2. Set up your Linux bootloader for [dual boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows)

For example, I have systemd-boot in ArchLinux configured like this:

```
tree /boot/loader
/boot/loader
├── entries
│   ├── arch.conf
│   └── windows.conf
└── loader.conf
```